# Identity Server - Password expiry feature

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to enable password expiry using the following setup: https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-passwordPolicy/blob/master/docs/config.md

I applied all the steps except for section "Enabling Email Notifications" on identity server 6.1.0.

However, when i changes the password of an existing user and changes the last password change timestamp from the user profile, and then attempt to request an access token, instead of getting an error that the password expired, i got an access token successfully. To note that the config under deployment.toml is:

```
[[event_handler]]
name= "passwordExpiry"
subscriptions =["POST_UPDATE_CREDENTIAL", "POST_UPDATE_CREDENTIAL_BY_ADMIN", "POST_ADD_USER", 
"PASSWORD_GRANT_POST_AUTHENTICATION"]
[event_handler.properties]
passwordExpiryInDays= "2"
enableDataPublishing= false
priorReminderTimeInDays= "0"
```

Comment: What is the grant type you used to get the access token? what is the used password; is that the old password or the newly changed password? Regarding `changes the last password change timestamp from the user profile` -> Did you manually change this field or based on password change last password change property got updated?

Comment: grant_type = password. And i modified the field "Last Password Update" to simulate that the last password update was very old so the current password should become expired (i did this manually based on the documentation). And i used the current password while getting the token.

Answer (score 1):

Password expiry validation support for Password Grant[1] was added to WSO2 Identity Server product recently and It is not available in the IS 6.1 vanila pack.

By the way this support was available in the IS 6.1.0 latest u2 updated pack. If you have a Subscription to the WSO2 Update service, you can update the WSO2 IS 6.1.0 to an update level higher than 6.1.0.1 or otherwise, you can apply a patch with the fix mentioned here[1]. Or else you can try the flow in the Identity server master branch.

[1]https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/13876

Comment: okay thank you noted.